# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for a beginner

Tags: python, syntax-error

Hi I have been programming in java for a couple of months now and I have had some time off so I wanted to try out some python so I decided to try and write my java programs into python but I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong on this piece of code. I want to use a for loop and a while loop in this program just for practice but I keep getting an error

Here is my code:

```
breakLine = "\n-------------------------------------------------\n"

print breakLine

startReading = float(raw_input("Please enter the odometer start reading in Miles "))
endReading = float(raw_input("Now please enter the odometer end reading in Miles "))
totalMiles = endReading - startReading
totalGal = 0.0

gals = [];
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];

for i in range (0, 5):
    gals.insert(i, float(raw_input("Enter gals for " + days[i] + " ")))
    totalGal += gals[i]
    i += 1

avgFuel = totalMiles / totalGal

print breakLine
print "Below is some information about your weeks travel"
print breakLine

print ("{0:20} \t {1:20}".format("DAY", "GALLONS USED"))
print breakLine

x = 0

while x < len(days):
    print ("{0:20} \t {1:20}".format(days[x], str(gals[x]))
    x += 1

print breakLine
print "You used a total of:", totalGal, "gallons this week"
print "You travelled a total of:", totalMiles, " Miles this week"
print "Your average fuel consumption for the week is:", avgFuel, "MPG"
```

and here is the error I get

```
  File "Week1-2.py", line 31
    x += 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

any help on this would be great

Comment: Count the parenthesis in the previous line. (Hint: the problem is often one line before the one where the error message points to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed parentheses enclose at the end of the print

```
x = 0
while x < len(days):
    print ("{0:20} \t {1:20}".format(days[x], str(gals[x])))
    x += 1
```

To aviod those type of problems i recommend to use an IDE like [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) it will help you to find mistakes easy.

Comment: what an idiot i am thanks man was tearing my hair out, i was using notepad but i'll give pycharm a try